# Clojure function/macro to apply functions until one returns something other than nil

Tags: clojure

Currently I have some code like this:

```
(defn compute-issue [some args] (or (age-issue some args) (name-issue some args)))
```

More issue types are coming.
Is there something like this:

```
(defn compute-issue [some args] (first-not-nil [age-issue name-issue] some args))
; Where first-not-nil would be something like
(defn first-not-nil [fs & args]
  (if (empty? fs)
    nil
    (let [result (apply (first fs) args)]
      (if (nil? result)
        (recur (rest fs) args)
        result))))
```

I'm new to Clojure. Am I reinventing an existing function?

Comment: maybe use `recur`?

Comment: Edited to correct code, thanks @DanielPuiu

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a similar function [`some-fn`](https://clojuredocs.org/clojure.core/some-fn) in clojure.core:

> Takes a set of predicates and returns a function f that returns the *first logical true value*
>   returned by one of its composing predicates against any of its arguments, else it returns
>   logical false. Note that f is short-circuiting in that it will stop execution on the first
>   argument that triggers a logical true result against the original predicates.

The key differences are `some-fn` returns another function for the actual function application, and that function will *also* discard `false` results, which it sounds like you may not want. This is another simple way to phrase it:

```
(defn first-not-nil [fs & args]
  (first
   (for [f fs
         :let [r (apply f args)]
         :when (some? r)]
     r)))
```

Comment: Some differences between what I've written and some-fn: some-fn handles predicates, so just one argument at a time, and it will discard "false" responses. But, as for now, I'm fine with all these. Thanks a lot!